# Run some JavaScript after Sortable done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to run some JavaScript immediately after Sortable has completed moving a row, to update the move in a database table.  Where in Sortable can I trap this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although your question is kind of vague I think what you want to do is run some javascript when a sortable element is moved.

This can easily be done using the update event of the sortable, which as you can see in the JQuery-UI sortable's documentation is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

Here's more info http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

So what you need to do is something like this:

```
$('#sortableRows').sortable({
  update: function (event, ui) {

  insert your code and update your database table here 

  }
})
```

I really hope I helped you out!